# iPad profile from Cisco Meraki invalid

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-device-management

I just setup a bunch of iPads to get a profile from our Cisco Meraki MDM server and I am getting an error as follows in the Event log:

`name: Profile name, error: The profile "Profile Name" is invalid, status: Error`

Have any one seen this error before?

Answer (score 1):

Ok here was the fix.

I had to create a new Profile from scratch and then Tag it to the iPads and the profile pushed out fine.

**Beware**

I originally tried to make a copy of my first profile and got the same error message above - it wasn't until I created a brand new profile from scratch it fixed the issue.

Just a bad profile I guess